# API takes more time to respond in pending state than it shows in chrome network tab

Tags: javascript, reactjs, https, google-chrome-devtools, superagent

In my react redux application, using saga and superagent client to make asynchronous https api calls.

Api stays in pending state for around 4-5 secs and then below is timing analysis i got shows took miliseconds to respond. but on clock it took 5 secs around. why is this lag. this happens even if no other parallel requests are there

[image]

**and if i hit the same api through postman or curl. respond faster in ms.**

Below is the api client code:

```
    constructor() {
    methods.forEach(
        method =>
            (this[method] = (
                path: string,
                { params, data, timeout, authToken }: APIRequest = {}
            ) =>
                new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
                    const request = superagent[method](formatUrl(path));
                    request.timeout(timeout || 60000);
                    request.set('Authorization', authToken || this.getToken());
                    if (params) {
                        request.query(params);
                    }

                    if (data) {
                        request.send(data);
                    }

                    request.then((body: Response) => {
                        resolve(body.body)
                    }).catch((err: ResponseError) => {

                        // HACK to redirect to session expired
                        if (err.status === 401) {
                            if (window.location.href.indexOf('/customer/') > -1) {
                                window.history.pushState('', '', '/customer/session-expired')
                            } else {
                                window.history.pushState('', '', '/designer/session-expired')
                            }
                        }
                        reject(err)
                    });
                }))
    );
}
```

Below is the saga code to call api:

```
const result = yield SpacecraftBackendClient.post(
  `/api/v1.0/xyz/${abc}/init3D`,
  {
    data: {
      abc,
      sessionId,
      xyz: convertConnectionType(controller)
    }
  },
);
yield takeLatest(cartActionTypes.INIT_3D, init3D);
```